# Need help tracking the origin of a weird problem

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on an app that works with databases. Whenever I create more than one data table in my app, then erase one, and then try to close the app, it won't close. I added an event handler to the `FormClosing` event, and the `Cancel` property of `FormClosingEventArgs` is `true`. How can I track where is this property being set to `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario is usually caused by one of the controls on your form being stuck in validation. If you are handling the `Validating` event on any controls and you set `e.Cancel = true` in the handler for that event, then the initial value of the `Cancel` property in the handler for `FormClosing` will also be `true`.

If, by chance, your database app is using a `DataGridView` control, one of the cells may still be in edit mode when you come to close the form.