# Why do this two ListBoxes look different if their properties are identical?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

If I make a Visual Studio 2010 WinForms project and let the wizard add `Form1`. Then I add a `ListBox` to `Form1`. Then I add a form with "*Project/Add Windows Form*", and add a `ListBox` to that form (`Form2`). And then change in my "*Program.cs*" file the line `Application.Run(new Form1());` for `Application.Run(new Form2());`, the `ListBox` in the `Form2` looks as if it has an empty line I can select (It has a focus rectangle on the first line), but the `ListBox` in `Form1` doesn't. How is this possible? I compared the properties of both forms and list boxes and they are identical.

I know this doesn't seem to be a big deal, but I found out this difference when trying to find the cause of another [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020289/need-help-tracking-the-origin-of-a-weird-problem), coincidently related to another `ListBox` with an empty focus rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It's just because there is a `Button` in `Form1`. Something with the focus being automatically in the `ListBox` when there is no other control. Had nothing to do with my other problem. Would delete my question if I'd know how.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't change the `...run(new Form1())..` to `...Form 2())..` do you have no empty line at the startup of form 1..? interesting...

.....

I just rebuild your conctruct locally... you're right.. any help..?

Answer (score 0):

Check the proporties of Form1 and Form2 if they are the sames.
I guess the user control into them inherits of the parrent's style.